# Combine value strings of two dataframes in corresponding locations within each dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for python code to paste value strings of two dataframes with identical column names, dimensions and datatype (Strings).

I want to create a new dataframe by pasting each element of DF1 & DF2 together which is in the corresponding location within each dataframe and have a "," delimiter between each string.

[Input dataframes (DF1 & DF2) and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdGkH.png)

Equivalent R code would be using matrices: matrix(paste(DF1,DF2, sep=";"),nrow = nrow(DF1), dimnames=dimnames(DF1))

Is there a way to do this with python? Appears like it should be simple but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could add columns together directly, and use `pd.concat` to collect them into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["big", "small"], "b": ["good", "bad"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["shrimp", "lobster"], "b": ["will", "omen"]})

pd.concat([df1[col] + "," + df2[col] for col in df1],
          axis="columns")

#                a          b
# 0     big,shrimp  good,will
# 1  small,lobster   bad,omen
```

EDIT:
Better yet, you can just add the dataframes in their entirety.

```
df1 + "," + df2
#                a          b
# 0     big,shrimp  good,will
# 1  small,lobster   bad,omen
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1) \
        .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1) \
        .unstack()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     A    B    C
0  z,f  x,h  c,j
1  v,t  b,y  n,u
2  a,u  s,i  d,o
```

Comment: @Delagator123. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks! This worked well. Although @TMBailey df1 + "," + df2 appears to be the most simple approach.

Comment: Feel free to accept his answer if you prefer this method.